# Why did Madhouse list Korean staffs in English on their credit?

Tags: anime-production, no-guns-life

The closing credits of the anime series *No Guns Life* include credits to staff members of the Korean studio **DR movie**.

[image]

(screen shot from Funimation, [No Guns Life](https://www.funimation.com/shows/no-guns-life/renegade-extended/?qid=undefined) episode 1, @22:10)

On other series I have noticed that, when non-Japanese staffers are given credit, it has been in the language of those people.  So I would have expected the credits for them here to be shown with the Korean alphabet, not the Latin one.

Is there a reason Madhouse (the primary studio) chose not to credit them in Korean?  Incidentally, when I was researching this, I learned that Madhouse is a partial owner of DR movie.

Comment: Kind of similar to the previous question: [Language consistency in anime credits](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/44050).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this question can be reworded to a more generalized situation by adding more examples, though the current premise of the question may still be valid even with a sample of 1.